# How to store and retrieve Widget data in the database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop a plugin which helps to upload a image title and description associated with it. After that display the same in front-end . Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom News Scroller
Plugin URI: http://url.com
Description: description.
Author: name
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://url.com
 */

 class CustomNewsScrollerWidget extends WP_Widget
{
        function CustomNewsScrollerWidget() {
        $widget_options = array(
        'classname'     =>      'custom-news-scroller-widget',
        'description'   =>      'Helps to scroll news'
        );

        parent::WP_Widget('custom_news_scroller_widget', 'Custom News Scroller', $widget_options);
    }


    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract ( $args, EXTR_SKIP );
        $title = ( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : 'A simple widget';
        $body = ( $instance['body'] ) ? $instance['body'] : 'A simple message'
        ?>
        <?php echo $before_widget ?>
        <?php echo $before_title . $title . $after_title ?>
        <p><?php echo $body ?></p>
        <?php 
    }

    function update() {

    }

    function form($instance) {
        ?>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">
            Title:
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" 
            name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" 

            value="<?php echo esc_attr($instance['title'])  ?>" />

        </label>

            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('description'); ?>">
            Description:
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('description'); ?>" 
            name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('description'); ?>" 

            value="<?php echo esc_attr($instance['description'])  ?>" />

        </label>
        <?php

    }

}

function custom_news_scroller_widget_init() {
    register_widget("CustomNewsScrollerWidget");
}
add_action('widgets_init','custom_news_scroller_widget_init');
```

I have a 2 input text box which input the title and description. How to store these information in database? And how to retrieve the same from database?

Comment: What does not work for you? What exact error do you have? Did you check the [example in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)?

Answer (score 1):

```
function update() {

    }
```

your function update is empty .. this function is used by widgets to save data ..

http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API refer here !